# Form elements are not disabling in modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to disable form elements except of this class custom_case.so I have done like this.

```
$(":input").not("td.custom_case  *").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

but when i click on table row modal dialog will open where all the elements are enabled in modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop()` not `attr()` and `true`:

```
$(":input").not("td.custom_case  *").prop("disabled", true);
```

As the [jQuery docs for `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) state:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected,
>   or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] then which includes your HTML? Your selector is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

```
$(":input:not(.custom_case  *)").attr("disabled", true);
```

**Note:** If `.custom_case` is the class of the element you want to exempt, not need for `*`